# Problem with specialchars/tokens sent by email with rules module

Tags: 6, rules, tokens

I'm using rules module in D6

I have an encoding problem in the email's body sent by a rule while using tokens:

```
Name : [node:field_company_nid-title]
```

In the email, it appears like that:

```
Name : L&#039;entreprise exemple
```

With php it works :

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode( $string )
```

but i'd rather to use tokens !

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The good way is to use the -raw output :

```
[node:field_company_nid-title-raw]
```